# how to parse json string to array

Tags: javascript, json

I got data from back and and assigned this data to javascript var

```
 var data={"Hunt_Valley": {"code": "HV", "latidue": "39.4900013", "longitude": "-76.6585074"}, "Mexico City": {"code": "MEX", "latidue": "19.4326077", "longitude": "-99.133208"}, "Kiev": {"code": "KBP", "latidue": "50.4501", "longitude": "30.5234"}}
```

I want to iterate this data and assign each data to var and generate array
so the array will be like

```
           images: [
                    {title:"Hunt_Valley", latitude:39.4900013, longitude:-76.6585074},
                     {title:"Mexico City", latitude:19.4326077, longitude:-99.133208},
                    {title:"Kiev", latitude:50.4501, longitude:30.5234},
```

What is the way to iterate this string.

Thanks you in advance

Comment: It all starts with a JSON.parse()

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa Looks like it's already parsed.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Isn't it easier to process the data when everything is together in one object, rather than scattered across different arrays?

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = { images: [] };
for (var city in data) {
    result.images.push( {
        title: city,
        latitude: data[city].latitude,
        longitude: date[city].longitude
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 yup this is the one acc to the new req... :) Hopefully doesn't change again... lol